# ordered swap on simple collection

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net-3.5

I have a method that swaps two items:

```
swap( collection['a'], collection['b'] );  // result = 'b', 'a'
swap( collection[0], collection[1] ); // result = collection[1], collection[0]
swap( 0, collection.indexOf(collection[1]) ); // result collection[1] index, 0
```

- The swap method cannot be modified.
- Four possible values stored in a collection: 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
- Swapped to always be in this order 'd', 'b', 'a', 'c'
- Any of the four possible values may or may not be in the collection

Please help me to implement this algorithm.

Thanks!

For those that care, this is not homework.

**Examples:**

```
//Example 1:
//collection contains: 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
//desired order: 'd', 'b', 'a', 'c'
swap(0, collection.IndexOf(collection['d']));
swap(1, collection.IndexOf(collection['b']));
swap(2, collection.IndexOf(collection['a']));
swap(3, collection.IndexOf(collection['c']));

//Example 2:
//collection contains: 'a', 'b', 'c'
//desired order: 'b', 'a', 'c' 
swap(0, collection.IndexOf(collection['b']));
swap(1, collection.IndexOf(collection['a']));
swap(2, collection.IndexOf(collection['c']));
```

Comment: Is this homework? What are you trying to do? Can you give an example of how it could be used?

Comment: I believe the question should answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I realize now (thanks to those that answered) that using a custom IComparer like this below removes the need to use swap.**   This solution guarantees the order and will still work correctly when one of the 5 possible values is missing.

```
class CustomOrder : IComparer<Series>
{
    static readonly Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = 
        new Dictionary<string, int>() 
    { 
        {"Excellent", 1}, 
        {"Very Good", 2},
        {"Average", 3},
        {"Bad", 4},
        {"Very Bad", 5}
    };

    public int Compare(Series x, Series y)
    {
        return dictionary[x.Name].CompareTo(dictionary[y.Name]);
    }
}

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Series[] sortedSeries = chart.Series.ToArray();
        Array.Sort(sortedSeries, new CustomOrder());
    } 
}
```

**Old solution using swap (for reference)**

I don't like it, but this seems to work. Anyone have any better ideas?

```
int count = collection.Count;

// don't need to swap if there is only one element
if (count > 1)
{
    // have to run once for each letter 
    sortCollection(count);
    sortCollection(count);      
    sortCollection(count);
    sortCollection(count);
}

private void sortCollection(int count)
{
    if (collection.Contains(collection['c']))
    {
        // take care of last element
        collection.Swap(count - 1, collection.IndexOf(collection['c']));
    }
    if (collection.Contains(collection['a']) && collection.Contains(collection['b']))
    {
        // take care of middle elements
        if(collection[1] != collection['b'])
        collection.Swap(collection['a'], collection['b']);
    }
    if (collection.Contains(collection['d']))
    {
        // take care of first element
        if(collection[0] != collection['d'])
        collection.Swap(0, collection.IndexOf(collection['d']));
    }
}
```

Comment: In some places your indices are integers in the range 0 through 4, and in other places your indices are characters 'a' through 'd'. Is this truly how your collection can be indexed  --  both ways?

Comment: Yes.  The collection can be indexed on integer or string (although I used character in the example)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're looking for a sort with an indirect comparison. I.e., instead of comparing the letters themselves, you compare values they look up in a table. If you'll pardon C++ syntax, the general idea would be something like this:

```
class my_cmp { 
    static const int positions[] = { 2, 1, 3, 0};
public:
    bool operator<(char a, char b) { 
        return positions[a-'a'] < positions[b-'a'];
    }
}:

std::sort(collection.begin(), collection.end(), my_cmp());
```

`std::sort` will use `swap` to move the elements in the collection. Although the syntax will obviously be a little different, from what I remember when I last used it, the same general idea should apply reasonably well to C# as well.

Answer (score 2):

Jerry's C++ solution adapted to C#:

```
using System;
using IComparer = System.Collections.IComparer;

class CustomOrder: IComparer
{
    static readonly int[]   positions = { 2, 1, 3, 0 };

    public int Compare( object x, object y )
    {
        return positions[(char)x-'a'].CompareTo( positions[(char)y-'a'] );
    }
}

class Startup
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[]  collection  = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

        Console.WriteLine( collection );            // abcd
        Array.Sort( collection, new CustomOrder() );
        Console.WriteLine( collection );            // dbac
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you update this to be able to use a string instead of a character?  I used simple data in my question, but in reality the data I need to sort is of string datatype. Thanks.

Comment: Simply replace `char` with `string`, and perhaps you need to change single quote characters to double quote characters (it's been ages since I did anything C# so I don't remember its detailed syntax). I think the difficult thing to do is to make this use a custom `swap`, e.g. if you want to see which swaps are executed. I couldn't see any easy way to make the `Sort` method use a custom swap, or any way whatsoever. But since there are very few elements a hand-coded insertion sort would be efficient enough. It's like, for each value, insert it at its proper position. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: It isn't that simple.  You cannot subtract an integer from a string, in any C based langauges.

Comment: Just decide what your strings are, then do the appropriate thing. :-) E.g. for your original specification the strings are single-letter strings. And for that, can you see a way to extract the first `char` of a string? Cheers & hth.,

Comment: subt13: it is easy enough to change a string to char[] in C#: simply call ToCharArray() on the string, after the call to Array.Sort with the resorted collection to get it back to a string call new String(collection).  Or am I missing something in you objection to this solution?

Comment: @subt13: I suggest that you edit your question to include the relevant info that you omitted or gave incorrect information about,like, your elements are strings, not characters, and your collection is not an array or other collection with `Sort` method, but something (that you then need to specify unambiguously).